# Connecting to a hyperlink found in another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is is possible to create a usable hyperlink to a URL listed in another workbook?

I'm creating a dashboard link to a social media post with the most likes. The post's URL is listed in another workbook. Trying to avoid having to make a direct link to a post as this would need to be manually updated as the data changes.

Formula tried:

=hyperlink('drive:\folder[workbook.xlsx]worksheet'!$A$1,"Click Here to See Post")

$A$1 contains the post's URL pulled from a list of posts using index(match(max) formula

Answer (score 0):

Your square brackets seem to be in the wrong place. Try:

```
=HYPERLINK('drive:\folder\[workbook.xlsx]worksheet'!$A$1, "Click Here to See Post")
```

Note if you have both workbooks open you can begin typing the formula then click `A1` in the other sheet; Excel will automatically fill in the link location for you.

Comment: I fixed the post, that was just a typo. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'm still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Try replacing the value in `A1` with some text instead of index/match/max - if it works with regular text, then it'll be something to do with the way you're constructing your link value.